# HTML / CSS - Position Sticky and transform without resizing viewport

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, sticky

In my website, I have elements that use transformations. I have noticed that these transformations resize the viewport. Normally I would solve this by giving the html and body `overflow-x: hidden` but then my header with `position: sticky` doesn't work.

How can I prevent the transformed elements from resizing the viewport and keep using `position: sticky`?

I have added an example below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scale {
  padding: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: scale(2);
  position: relative;
  z-index 1;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
  right 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>I want this header to remain sticky</header>
<div class="scale">
But I don't want this div to resize the x-axis of the viewport.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another container where you can apply `overflow:hidden`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scale {
  padding: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: scale(2);
  position: relative;
  z-index 1;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
  right 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>I want this header to remain sticky</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="scale">
    But I don't want this div to resize the x-axis of the viewport.
  </div>
</div>
```